# Iterate an array infinite times with for each and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, settimeout

I have this method in `myClass`. When it arrives at the end of the array, I want it to start again from 0, however at the moment it just stops.

```
this.jsonParse = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numberOfPhotos; i++){
         (function(index, selector, timing, arrayLength){
            setTimeout(function() {
               $(selector).css('background-color': obj_gallery.images[index].hex);
            }, index*timing);            
         })(i, this.slideWrap, this.timing,this.numberOfPhotos);
    }
}
```

I have tried something like this below, but it doesn't work.

```
if (index >= arrayLength) {
    index = 0;
}
```

**NB** The local variables like `this.numberOfPhotos` etc. have been previously defined.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: yes sorry... http://codepen.io/StefanoVollono/pen/MYLbaz

Comment: `.css('background-color': obj_gallery...`. That syntax doesn't look right.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but did you try `if (i > arrayLength) { i = 0; }`?

Comment: @elclanrs I miss the quotes on value of background-color (right?), but it works done... look the Pen. My problem is on cicle for.

Comment: I'm not sure why it works, but it should be a comma, not a colon.

Comment: @yatrix yes, but i = 0 doesn't rewrite the value....

Comment: @elclanrs yes it should be .....css( "background-color", "yellow" );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think I understand what you want to do (rotate the images indefinitely), your approach is rather horrible. Assuming you've got 1000 images in the rotation, you'd have at least 1000 timers running and you'd load all 1000 images at once.

Instead I'd use a far less complex approach using a modulo operator on your index and a simple function to update one of two gallery images.

First, the basic HTML is very minimalistic:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img id="gallery_a" onload="galleryLoaded()" />
    <img id="gallery_b" onload="galleryLoaded()" />
</div>
```

The `onload` events are used to actually toggle the visible image once they've been loaded and to prevent switching images before loading is complete.

I've setup [an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Smaxx/rocLb6jg/) to showcase this approach.

There's no special CSS needed for this. For the transition effect to work, you'll need some minimal setup for the second image:

```
#gallery_b {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

The periodically called function (which may also be initiated by a button or some link) will update the current image's index and swap the image currently invisible:

```
// This function will init the switch
function galleryNext() {
    if (gallery_switching)
        return;

    // Prevent multiple switches at once    
    gallery_switching = true;

    // Get the next index (the modulo will make it wrap around)
    gallery_index = (gallery_index + 1) % images.length;

    // Update the inactive image
    // This could also update some link target or similar
    document.getElementById(gallery_second ? 'gallery_a' : 'gallery_b').src = images[gallery_index];

    // Toggle the next image
    gallery_second = !gallery_second;
}
```

The `onload` event will switch images (essentially just hiding the second image as needed):

```
// This function is a callback once the next image has been loaded
function galleryLoaded() {
    if (!gallery_switching)
        return;
    gallery_switching = false;

    // If the second image is the next, we'll have to hide it now (since we want to show the first one)
    document.getElementById('gallery_b').style.opacity = gallery_second ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Last but not least you'll have to setup the interval and get the very first image to show immediately.

```
setTimeout(galleryNext, 0); // Fake "onload" here
setInterval(galleryNext, 2500); // Switch once every 5 seconds
```

Of course you could just set the initial `src` for the image somewhere else as well.

Comment: As an added note, if you'd like to have variable times on your images, you could simply use `setTimeout()` in `galleryLoaded()` rather than the fixed interval callback.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach, with recursion, instead of incremental timeouts. First I'd create an abstraction that you can reuse:

```
function cycle(delay, f, xs) {
   var run = function(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         f(xs[i])
         i += 1
         if (i >= xs.length) {
            i = 0
         }
         run(i)
      }, delay)
   }
  f(xs[0])
  run(1)
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
this.jsonParse = function(){
    var $el = $(this.slideWrap)
    var bgcolor = function(img) {
        $el.css('background-color', img.hex)
    }
    cycle(this.timing, bgcolor, obj_gallery.images)     
};
```

For example: [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/elclanrs/pen/xbBPzr?editors=101)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple `cycle` implementation using [Javascript Generator Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#generator_functions). This is inspired by [Ruby's `Enumerable#cycle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle):

```js
function* cycle(values) {
  let iterationCount = 0;
  let valuesLength = values.length;

  while (true) {
    yield values[iterationCount % valuesLength];
    iterationCount++;
  }
}

infiniteLoop = cycle(["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]);

console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // "a"
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // "b"
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // "c"
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // 1
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // 2
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // 3

console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // "a"
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // "b"
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // "c"
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // 1
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // 2
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // 3

console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // "a"
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // "b"
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // "c"
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // 1
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // 2
console.log(infiniteLoop.next().value); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use setInterval() instead - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogVodo

```
 this.jsonParse = function(){
  // Ho bisogno di una funziona anonimica per passare i parametri, poiche il setTimeout non lo fa.
  var slideWrap = this.slideWrap;
  var timing = this.timing;
  var numberOfPhotos = this.numberOfPhotos;
  var index =0;
  setInterval(function() {
     $(".gallery").css('background-color', obj_gallery.images[index].hex);
     index++;
     if (index === numberOfPhotos){
        index = 0;
     }
        },timing);            
  };
```

Comment: This answer does not reflect good coding practices, I tried to make it as elaborate as possible :)

Comment: Sorry @buzzy, why your answer does not reflect good coding practices?? thanks

Comment: 1) You should cache the selector. 2) You probably can have a simpler check than the index === numberOfPhotos. 3) You may want to save the return value of that setInterval to stop it. I just wrote it as an example of how setInterval can solve your issue.

Comment: @Buzzy: Just use modulo: `index = (index + 1) % numberOfPhotos`.