# Looping through array of colors infinite amount of times

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button with a default background color(black). I want to change the background color (from an array) of this button when hovering over it. I have it working at a fundamental level, but I want it to repeat the loop over and over.
this is what i have so far.

```js
var color = ['#3e50a2', '#faa51a', '#ed1c24', '#2a9446'];
var i = -1;

document.querySelector('.customBtn').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  i = 1 < color.length ? ++i : 0;
  document.querySelector('.customBtn').style.background = color[i]
});
document.querySelector('.customBtn').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelector('.customBtn').style.background = '#000';
})
```

```html
<a class="customBtn">Button</a>
```

Comment: Use a `setInterval`?

Comment: You're not changing the content of `color`, so what is `i = 1 < color.length ? ++i : 0;` supposed to do other than constantly increment `i` on every `mouseover` event?

Comment: Should be `i < color.length` (is what I meant to say :-)

Comment: Why not use a CSS animation for this?

Comment: You may want to consider using an approach like those outlined in the answers to [Iterate an array infinite times with for each and setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29326937/215552)

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to reset the value of `i` with this `i = 1 < color.length ? ++i : 0;` but it doesn't. This will continuously increase the value never resetting it because 1 is always less than the length of the array.

I think you meant to increment the value and then reset if it's too big:

```
i = ++i < color.length ? i : 0;
```

Here's the complete code. I've refactored the query selector as there's no point to doing it more than once, and changed the `mouseout` background colour so you can read the button

```js
var color = ['#3e50a2', '#faa51a', '#ed1c24', '#2a9446'];
var i = -1,
    btn = document.querySelector('.customBtn');

btn.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  i = ++i < color.length ? i : 0;
  btn.style.background = color[i];
});

btn.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  // revert to default colour
  btn.style.background = '';
})
```

```html
<input type="button" class="customBtn" value="My button" />
```

Comment: @Andreas just changing `i` instead of `1` will make `i` range from 0 to `color.length`. With the proposed solution, `i` will range from 0 to `color.length -1`, which is the correct behavior

Comment: Not so. If `i` was 3 then `i < color.length ? ++i : 0` would return 4 which is beyond the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

**If you must use javascript, take a look at the second example.**

### Pure CSS solution

You could accomplish this with a [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), which would be both more efficient and less error prone. Unless there's a specific reason you need to use javascript here I'd strongly recommend this approach.

This example could be modified to do hard transitions instead of fading from one color to the next, but here's a quick demo:

```css
button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

button:hover {
  animation: buttonhover 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes buttonhover {
  0% {
    background: #3e50a2;
  }
  25% {
    background: #faa51a;
  }
  50% {
    background: #ed1c24;
  }
  75% {
    background: #2a9446;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
```

---

### Javascript Solution

If you must use javascript for whatever reason, you can use the [% operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to keep from running off the end of the colors array:

```js
const colors = ['#3e50a2', '#faa51a', '#ed1c24', '#2a9446'];
let index = 0;
let interval;

const hover = (e) => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
  }, 300);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('mouseover', hover);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
});
```

```css
button {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `i = 1 < color.length ? ++i : 0;`  with `i = (i+1 < color.length) ? ++i : 0;`. That's all.

```js
var color = ['#3e50a2', '#faa51a', '#ed1c24', '#2a9446'];
var i = -1;

document.querySelector('.customBtn').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  i = (i+1 < color.length) ? ++i : 0;
  document.querySelector('.customBtn').style.background = color[i]
});

document.querySelector('.customBtn').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelector('.customBtn').style.background = '#000';
})
```

```html
<a class="customBtn">Button</a>
```